# How to specify my own feature extractor in TextBlob?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, textblob

I followed this tutorial:
http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/classifiers.html#feature-extractors
And I wrote an extractor:

```
def phrases_extractor(document):
    r.extract_keywords_from_text(document)
    words = r.get_ranked_phrases()
    feats = {}
    for w in words:
        feats["contains({0})".format(w)] = True
    return feats
```

But I don't know why the docs says that there should be "contains... = False"
How can I do that? Should I firstly collect all the possible words and add them to the dictionary with False value?

Answer (score 0):

I've been reviewing this same thing. I'm pretty sure this is a typo. It would have to be *True* because the dictionary is indicating that the last word is ____. False would mean the last word isn't ____ and the example is not set up that way.